# Python global name not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to test the following simple object:

```
class WebCorpus(object):
    def __init__(self):
        _index = {}
        _graph = {}
        _ranks = {}
        _corpusChanged = False

    def lookup(self, keyword):
        if keyword in _index:
            return _index[keyword]
        return None
# (some irrelevant code)
```

With:

```
from WebCorpus import WebCorpus

def test_engine():
    print "Testing..."
    content = """This is a sample <a href="http://www.example.com">webpage</a> with 
    <a href="http://www.go.to">two links</a> that lead nowhere special."""
    outlinks = ["http://www.example.com", "http://www.go.to"]

    corpus = WebCorpus()
    assert corpus.lookup("anything") == None
#(some more code)
test_engine()
```

But it gives me an error: NameError: global name '_index' is not defined. I don't understand this, _index is clearly defined in the `__init__` !? What is my mistake here? 
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to set class variables in the class method, you should use `self`:

```
class WebCorpus(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._index = {}
        self._graph = {}
        self._ranks = {}
        self._corpusChanged = False

    def lookup(self, keyword):
        if keyword in self._index:
            return self._index[keyword]
        return None
```

Or, you can simplify the code and set variables like this (I've also simplified `lookup` method):

```
class WebCorpus(object):
    _index = {}
    _graph = {}
    _ranks = {}
    _corpusChanged = False

    def lookup(self, keyword):
        return self._index.get(keyword)
```

Note, the second example is not equivalent to the first one, because class-level variables are used, see comments below.

Comment: The two example are not equivalent, in the second case, all instance of `WebCorpus` will share the `_index`, `_graph`, and `_ranks` attributes as they are class attributes and not instance attributes.

Comment: Agreed, but, keeping in mind that `__init__.py` doesn't accept any arguments, I think, this is what @ŞükrüHasdemir really wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Does that mean that once `_index`, for example, is set using one instance of `WebCorpus`, it will be the same for all instances @Sylvain?

Comment: @ŞükrüHasdemir: No, if you do `corpus = WebCorpus()` using the second implementation, then `corpus._index = {"key": "value"}` will override the dictionary for that specific instance. However, if you do `c1, c2 = WebCorpus(), WebCorpus()`, then `c1._index["key"] = "value"` will also change the content of `c2._index` (since they refer to the same object).

Comment: Yes, `_index` will be shared between instances.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that it's defining `_index` but then losing it after the `__init__` is run. You should append `self` to everything, so it's `self._index`, etc. This goes for the entire class, not just in the `__init__`.